# Object.fromEntries not working on old browsers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular app that has been developed on following specs:

```
> ng version
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/

Angular CLI: 14.0.7
Node: 16.17.0
Package Manager: npm 8.15.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.0.7
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.11
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.11
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.7
@angular/cdk                    14.0.6
@schematics/angular             14.0.7
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.7.4
```

The app works correctly when deployed via IIS on new browsers but I have to target old versions of Chrome due to legacy requirements. When I run the app on an old Chrome browser (version 63) I face following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
```

I looked it up and found out that `fromEntries` is supported in Chrome version >73.

What can I do in this situation? Can I use a polyfill, and if yes then how would I do that in Angular?

Or, is downgrading a specific package that uses this function also an option? I searched for `fromEntries` throughout my code and the only instance I found was in `C:\My Project\.angular\cache\14.2.11\babel-webpack\c8feead8cb3e88b701a0507c0d4f53a3.json`

Comment: *Can I use a polyfill* - yes. *how would I do that in Angular* - probably by reading *[documentation](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)*

Comment: Chrome 63 is almost 6 years old. Probably the best bet would be to look up the release history of the packages and use those from around that time. It's going to be a pain to support a browser that old anyway.

Comment: Using an old browser is also not recommented because of tons of security patches that were introduced in newer versions. However uses the old Chrome, please recommend them to upgrade.

Comment: A browser this old would better be used with JavaScript disabled, so if you want to support it, forget about Angular running in it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, I did the following:

1. Installed the [fromEntries polyfill NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyfill-object.fromentries)
2. Imported the package in `src\polyfills.ts` file: `import 'polyfill-object.fromentries'`